# Tracking down stack overflow in meteor/node fiber

Tags: node.js, meteor, v8, node-fibers

I'm seeing this crash now and am not familiar enough with the node fiber infrastructure to know where to begin interpreting the error or instrumenting the code...

```
Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
W202407-10:06:05.740(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/dauser/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W202407-10:06:07.363(-8)? (STDERR)                      throw(ex);
W202407-10:06:07.363(-8)? (STDERR)                            ^
W202407-10:06:07.363(-8)? (STDERR) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Meteor server restarted
```

As I understand it, something is recurring a little too enthusiastically, the server stack blows up, and it crashes. Unfortunately, I have no real idea where this offending function is--I looked at the my Deps.autorun call (just one at the moment) and it does not seem to be the trouble. None of my code is implemented with explicit recursion, and I don't have any reason to suspect large objects are being passed around. Obviously, I'm not really sure, of course.

I'm really just looking for advice on how to instrument the code to show me where things are getting out of hand. Since Meteor's doing a whole lot behind the scenes, it would be really useful if anyone could give me a few pointers as to where to look.

Just coming back to this, and am still pretty lost as to where to be looking. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663957/debugging-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) suggested updating to node 0.11.x would give me more info, but doing that doesn't seem to have added any more detail when it crashes.

The crash happens after any page interaction--that is, the server starts up and is functioning ok, but if I reload in the browser or interact with the page itself, BOOM!

By popular demand, here is the server code:

```
isAuthorized = () ->
    console.log "checking authorization"
    this.userId == Assets.getText('authorizedUsers')

Meteor.methods(
    isAuthorized : isAuthorized
    filePickerKey : () -> 
        # TODO: properly abstract this, rather than copy/paste...       
        if this.userId == Assets.getText('authorizedUsers')
            Assets.getText('fpKey')
        else
            Meteor.Error 403, 'Error 403: Forbidden')
```

uncommenting line 172 of future.js did not provide more details:

```
I2041-15:52:07.363(-8)? Resolve cb threw Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

And, here's the trouble I run into while trying to use node-inspector. I have been playing with this for the past half hour, so I'm likely just making some fundamental error, but:
I installed node-inspector via npm (npm install -g node-inspector).

then, I try

```
$ node-inspector &
[1] 3408
$ Node Inspector v0.6.2
  info  - socket.io started
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.

$ meteor &
[2] 3413
$ [[[[[ ~/Projects/indefinite-ways ]]]]]

=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/

$ kill -s USR1 3413
Hit SIGUSR1 - starting debugger agent.
debugger listening on port 5858
```

so far, so good. At this point, the client side is not open in my browser (i.e. no tab pointing at localhost:3000). I open up a Chrome tab pointing to localhost:5858, and see the source for meteor.js I set a breakpoint on line 6 of meteor.js

```
var Fiber = require('fibers');
```

and then open the meteor client tab (localhost:3000) and the aforementioned stack overflow pops up again. The debugger does not halt on line 6, or in any other way indicate that it has noticed. Same is true if I set a breakpoint at line 3.

Comment: my first suspicion would be that you write to files in your meteor project on startup or something, triggering a restart and hence a new write.. Can you tell more about when this happens?

Comment: Not sure if I'm following--I'm not (intentionally) writing anything to the project. That said, there's a lot of framework happening, and it is under git, so there is probably some metadata being written. This error popped up after listifying a template.

Comment: Is there any code you can provide? This is usually caused by either an infinite loop or trying to return an object that is too large. This is likely caused by your server side code. It would be your `Meteor.methods` functions most likely

Comment: I added the server code. The fpKey asset is just a single string. Same for the authorizedUsers asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slightly more helpful answer comes from the [unofficial Meteor FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq):

```
$ node-inspector &
$ NODE_OPTIONS='--debug-brk' mrt run &
```

This starts the node-inspector process in the background, and then starts meteor's node container listening with the right debugging flags set. Opening the Chrome tab to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858` let me step through.

Also, not *strictly* the answer to the question, but the offending line in the code above seems to be calling `Meteor.Error` in the server code. I'll still gladly accept an answer to this that would have identified that. I'm guessing that Meteor.Error is not at all EJSONable, and in attempting to parse it, the stack explodes.

Answer (score 4):

Try [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), it allows to inspect the callstack. This is a [video presentation](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/announcing-a-new-and-improved-node-js-debugger/) of how to use it, visually it looks like the chrome debugger (it's the same base source).

Comment: thanks for the lead. I posted the results of my attempt to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Line 173 of future.js](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/blob/master/future.js) forwards an exception onward to the next listener.  It appears in your case the next listener is the instance itself, resulting in a stack crashing loop.

Edit your future.js file (path referenced in OP) and uncomment the console.log line just above it... then you should see a more detailed explanation of what is going on.  If the console.log output isn't helpful to resolve, post here for further diagnostics.

My guess is it's related to a missing package, per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070315/deploy-meteor-to-official-meteor-servers-fibers).

Comment: thanks for the lead, but no dice! I edited the question, but long story short, there was no stack information. I even added a line to future.js to print ex.stack separately, which simply added the line "undefined" to the console output.

Comment: also, I re-installed fibers, just in case, but no change there.