# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on Modulus.io Server

Tags: node.js, meteor, modulus.io

I deployed my Meteor app on Modulus via their command line tools. I'm using v1.0.4rc4 of Meteor. After starting up the server everything works fine for a short time. After some time the server throws the following error and restarts when accessed by a client:

```
/mnt/data/1/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I never had that problem in my development environment and could not find anything about it online. Any idea what causes this?

Edit:
I played around a little bit more and it really only happens when one of my Cordova apps starts up and it seems before any of my code get's executed.

Comment: Looks like you have some profiling to do.  Check out this post for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843707/tracking-down-stack-overflow-in-meteor-node-fiber.  I'd also recommend taking a look at https://kadira.io/, they offer free metrics for your Meteor app

Comment: This error can be an infinite recursion

Comment: Its hard to say what causes this without much code. Typically this happens on the client & not the server & is caused by an infinite loop. Are you using `Tracker` or `Deps` on the server?

Comment: Tracker is only used on the client. And so far it doesn't happen while using the app but only from time to time when I start the Android or iOS Cordova app. That's why I'm not sure whether it's part of my code or something with Meteor and Cordova.

Comment: @SebastianRehm Its definitely server side code so can't be cordova/client side code. Im a bit unsure it will be `Tracker`. Do you have any code that runs callbacks into each other somehow? Do you have any cron tasks?

Comment: @imslavko Is there no way to find where the recursion comes from? The errors thrown from future.js are often very difficult to diagnose even if they're not coming from infinite recursions

Comment: @Akshat I don't have any Trackers on the server side the same goes for cron jobs. My server is pretty 'dumb' . I don't do anything automatically on the server side. My apps are subscribing to three collections and other than that there are only a few meteor methods that are called from the client side

Comment: Ok, I figured out that it has something to do with the raix:push package and posted the issue to its issue tracker.